# Curl/sed command not processing inputs correctly

Tags: linux, macos, curl, sed

I'm having some trouble with getting this to do what I want it to do.

```
read -p "URL to read: " U

read -p "Word to fin: " O

read -p "Filename: " F

curl -O $U | sed "s/\<$O\>/\*$O\*/g" > $F.txt
```

So basically what I want is to use `curl` to get a `.txt` file from a url, then sort through it to find the word specified by the user input. Then mark all those words with a `*` and put them in a file specified by the user. 
Almost the exact same code works in Linux, but this doesn't work on my Mac. Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

- `-O` makes `curl` store the downloaded file, *not output* it on `stdout`.
- word boundary metacharacters `\<` and `\>` are a GNU [extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#regexp-extensions). On BSD `sed`, you can use `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` instead.

This should work on OSX:

```
curl "$U" | sed "s/[[:<:]]$O[[:>:]]/\*$O\*/g" > $F.txt
```

Comment: Oh, ok. The problem that i didnt had that i didnt specify is that It´s still storing the entire http://....../ txt file in the new file. It doesnt find the words that I am trying to find.. 
Thank you so much toh, this helped!